# ServiceStack.Text set JsConfig on application start

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack-text

I set JsConfig in Application_Start method in my asp net mvc application

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
            JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
        }
```

and then I want to use extension method ToJson in my service method, for example

```
public string testMethod{
    //here code
    var obj = new TestObj{
        Id = 1,
        CurrentDate = DateTime.Now
    }
    return obj.ToJson();
}
```

and then I look a result and I see that json result in PascalCase and date in following format `Date(123455678990)`, but before I set in config for use the camelCase and utc format date

but I set config in my service method, for example:

```
public string testMethod{
    //here code
JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
            JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
    var obj = new TestObj{
        Id = 1,
        CurrentDate = DateTime.Now
    }
    return obj.ToJson();
}
```

I get the result that I want

Is it possible to set JsConfig properties on start my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the JsConfig properties at `Application_Start()` in your Global.asax does set the global configuration for your JSON serialization preferences as expected.

I've added an example of this in a test MVC Project [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/1876181fa19d3b7a38aa8a528676b8856946923f) which is working as expected, that sets static JsConfig configuration in `Application_Start()`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        JsConfig.Init(new Config {
            DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601,
            TextCase = TextCase.CamelCase
        });
        //...
    }
}
```

And serializes JSON in a controller:

```
return new HomeViewModel
{
    Name = name,
    Json = new TestObj { Id = 1, CurrentDate = DateTime.Now }.ToJson()
};
```

Which serializes as expected:

```
{"id":1,"currentDate":"2016-06-29T11:56:45.7517089-04:00"}
```

Comment: oh, thank you so much!
I understood your example, thanks
I will look for errors in my code